# Place Eclipse RCP Product plugins in a different folder

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is it possible to specify a different folder for the default Plug-ins folder that normally exists next to the .exe for an RCP product?

### Normal Setup:

```
Root
   |- product.exe
   |- product.ini
   |-- Plugins [Folder]
   | -- Configuration [Folder]
```

### Desired Setup:

```
Product
   |- product.exe
   |- product.ini
JarFiles [Folder]
   |- *.jar
Config
   |- config.ini
```

I have tried to update some entries in my product.ini to make this work, based on settings [listed here](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) such as:

--launcher.library=@user.dir/../JarFiles

or

--launcher.library=../JarFiles

But I get an error when I launch that says:

```
The Product executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.
```

Is there any runtime argument I can specify that properly tells the .exe that the Plugins and Configuration folder are elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `launcher.library` entry is not complete. It must point [directly to the plugin containing the launcher DLL](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/launcher.html), not only to your plugins folder, so it should look like

```
--launcher.library
../JarFiles/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.[your.operating.system][architecture][version]
```

Look at your installation to get the specific entries for the place holders. If you now also point to the changed configuration folder using the `-configuration` option, then you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I also discovered that the launcher library (equinox), MUST exist in a folder called 'Plugins'.  'JarFiles' did not work as a plugins location.  As well, I included '-startup
../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar'